# How can I cumulatively add or subtract values based on another column values using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum

I have a dataframe below that shows voltage output based on seconds. The `v_out` value is based on a displacement of either +/- 0.05 centimeters.

So when `v_out` gets more positive, then there is positive displacement compared to the last `v_out` value. When `v_out` gets more negative, the displacement is going in the `-` direction.

I have the initial `df` and I want to add a `sign` column that tells whether the `v_out` is positive or negative based on the previous `v_out` value. And, I want a `cumulative` column that keeps track of the added running total of the `sign` column.

**Initial `df`**

```
     secs     v_out
0     0.0 -1.179100
1    15.0 -1.179100
2    18.0 -1.179200
3    33.0 -1.181800
4    48.0  0.029461
```

**What I want**

```
     secs     v_out  sign  cumul
0     0.0 -1.179100  0.00  0.00
1    15.0 -1.179100  0.00  0.00
2    18.0 -1.179200 -0.05 -0.05
3    33.0 -1.181800 -0.05 -0.10
4    48.0  0.029461  0.05 -0.05
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The method to *look at* a _lagged value is named `shift`, and then we inspect if the values is positive, negative, or zero with an if-else construct.

So, first we'd construct the column `sign`. The logic can be packed into 1 line.

```
df['sign'] = (df.v_out - df.v_out.shift()).apply(lambda x: 0.05 if x > 0 else -0.05 if x < 0 else 0)
```

*btw, I'd often write this code interactively, but would recommend splitting it over a few lines so the logic is easier to follow if its going to be saved in a file)*

Then, to make the `cumul` column can be made through the application of the `cumsum` method.

```
df['cumul'] = df.sign.cumsum()
```

The final df looks like this:

```
   secs     v_out  sign  cumul                                                                                      
0   0.0 -1.179100  0.00   0.00                                                                                          
1  15.0 -1.179100  0.00   0.00                                                                                          
2  18.0 -1.179200 -0.05  -0.05                                                                                          
3  33.0 -1.181800 -0.05  -0.10                                                                                          
4  48.0  0.029461  0.05  -0.05`
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, there does seem to be an error though as the `cumul` output has a row that goes from `-5e-02` to the next row that is `-1.3877e-17` which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: `-1.3877e-17` is awefully close to `0`. You're possibly seeing some floating point error. use the `numpy.round` to keep only upto 2 decimal places. Without more information I can't offer any other suggestion.